# What did the * for th print function in python 3.x?

Tags: python, list, printing

what's the difference between

```
for i in list:
    print(*i,sep="")
```

And this print statement

```
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `print(*i,sep="")` statement print all values extracted from the *i* iterable, without any separator.

Where `print(I)` will print the *i* value. For an iterable, it will print the string representation of each value.

See the difference:

```
i = [1, 2, "hi"]

print(*i, sep="")
# -> 12hi
print(i)
# -> [1, 2, 'hi']
```

Explanation:

The `*i` syntax is called "unpacking": each value of an iterable (`list` or `tuple`) is extracted and pass as-is to the arguments of the `print` function (which take a variable list of parameters).

Comment: Do you need more explanation? If not, I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand if you look at an example with a list of lists.  In this case `i` is a list for each iteration of the loop.  With a simple print statement the output will be the entire list.

The `*` as used in this sample, tells python to unpack the list.  It's a nifty trick.  The separator is optional, but can be used to insert tabs, new lines, or any other separator you want.

```
stuff = [['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]


for i in stuff:
    print(i)


for i in stuff:
    print(*i)
```

Output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
['four', 'five', 'six']
one two three
four five six
```